# How to draw multiline formatted text on a canvas?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I m under delphi berlin and Firemonkey. Is their any algorithm available somewhere to draw on a canvas a **multiline formatted text** ? I already have this algo for android and ios, i need it only for Windows and Mac

Comment: If you already have the algorithm, then why can't you simply apply it universally?

Comment: @Rob because this algorithm use android api for android and ios api for ios :(

Comment: in windows you may use RichEdit or WebBrowser controls ;-)